# VS 2015 Building projects with DEVENV.com "An error occurred when applying the IIS Express settings to server URLfor project"

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, applicationhost

After we migrated the projects from VS 2010 to VS 2015, whenever I build a project from command prompt using devenv.com option, we are getting below popup.

> An error occurred when applying the IIS Express settings to server URL 'http://localhost:8157/'for project 'Myproject.web'. You may have to manually edit the applicationHost.config file and make the changes for your site to run correctly.

The same command we were using to build projects with VS 2010 and everything was working fine.

But when I delete "applicationhost.config" file from  "Solutions.vs\config" folder, open project with visual studio 2015 and build it and then If I again run the same command it works fine.

We cant do these manual actions every time when we take a new branch .